# Nmap random ip address scan order

Tags: nmap

There is an `-iR`, which allows to scan completely random hosts on the internet, but how do I scan, for example, a random subset of 10.0.0.0/8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an option to scan a subset of a passed network. You could make a  target IP list using the `--randomize-hosts (Randomize target host order)` option with a list scan (`-sL -n -oN filename`), cut the file to the number you want, then provide that random subset to Nmap with `-iL`.